# Automate Self-Extractor

Tags: java, self-extracting

I am a little new to programming so please bear with me.  I create a lot of self-extractors that I upload to a ftp site which my clients then download (with the self-extractor putting the files I zipped up to the right spot).  I am trying to automate this process on my end since it is rather repetitive.

I think I can figure out how to create the zip and how to upload the file once created but I cannot figure out how to create use winzip se to create a self-extractor from the created zip file.  WinZip has a command line interface but WinZIp SE apparently does not.

Any help would be appreciated...I am planning on writing this code in java btw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [What are the differences between the full WinZip Self-Extractor and the Personal Edition version?](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/184/)

> Self-extracting files can be created from the command line.

That being said, I'm not sure I would use Java to automate the tasks you are describing, it's not the best tool for that IMHO. I'd rather use shell scripting.

**Update:** (answering a comment from the OP) I'm really not a Windows specialist but I think that [Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) might be appropriate for the job (and it can be used to [query a MS Access database](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/08/13/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-query-a-microsoft-access-database-with-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, I am researching bat files now (never used em before).  Any recommendations on where I could look for info on how to use them.  I am going to need to read in info from a microsoft access table at some point in this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compress and decompress zip archives, just use any other command line utility, which you will call from your Java app. For example zip, and unzip: http://www.info-zip.org/

Answer (score 0):

7-zip is free and can do this on the command line, meaning you can make a batch script. 7za a -sfx MySelfExtractingzip.exe MyFolderContainingFiles/